# My iframe keeps displaying code injected as a string of text, not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery

For certain reasons, I have it so a div will contain code that I want an iframe to load:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi</h1>
</body>
</html>
</div>
<iframe id="MyFrame"></iframe>
```

My Javascript to get the text (the code) within the div above:

```
var DCode = document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML;
```

My Jquery to add the code to my iframe:

```
$('#MyFrame').contents().find('html').append(DCode);
```

When I view the document in my iframe, I see the html from the div inside but wrapped with double quotes and in the body. How can I get it to display as a page?

One thing I realized when using an alert box to display the code, the "<" are shown as the escape characters: & l t ;

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider -

1) Contents in MyDiv - `<head>` and `<body>` tags starts but do not end.
2) var "DCode" holds innerHTML but jquery appends "DString".. Variables are different.
 Is it a typo in asking the question?

Comment: Typos exactly, DString was a variable that stored DCode.toString(); which I realized was unnecessary.

Comment: The example had typos, my code still doesn't work though. My code is exactly as above with the typos fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue. Following code works fine for me -

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script>
    function copy()
    {
    var DCode = document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML;
    $('#MyFrame').contents().find('html').append(DCode);
    }
</script>   
</head>

<body onload="copy();">
<div id="MyDiv">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Hi</h1>
Div body
</body>
</html>
</div>

<iframe id="MyFrame"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing I realized when using an alert box to display the code, the "<" are shown as the escape characters: &lt;